# Text in a row to a repeating column

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel table where there are part codes in a column and for every part code, there are 3-4 subsections (1100-1400) with information which I need to attach to the part code in a column view.

The number of created rows depends on if there is data entered into subsection 1400. 1100-1300 has always information and needs to be converted into a table.

I don't even know from where to start so currently I have no code to show

I added a picture of how the data is represented and what the result should look like:
[image: Picture of data and result]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it like that

```
Option Explicit

Sub TransformA()

Dim rg As Range
Dim lastRow As Long, lineNo As Long, i As Long, j As Long
Dim shInput As Worksheet, shResult As Worksheet
Dim vDat As Variant, resDat As Variant
Dim subSection As String

    ' Make sure you run the code with the data in the Activesheet
    Set shInput = ActiveSheet

    ' And you have data which starts in row 4 with the heading in row 3
    ' otherwise adjust accordingly
    lastRow = shInput.Range("A4").End(xlDown).Row
    Set rg = shInput.Range("A4:I" & lastRow)

    vDat = rg
    ReDim resDat(1 To UBound(vDat, 1) * 4, 1 To 4)

    lineNo = 1

    For j = 1 To UBound(vDat, 1)

        For i = 0 To 2

            Select Case i
            Case 0: subSection = "1100"
            Case 1: subSection = "1200"
            Case 2: subSection = "1300"
            End Select

            resDat(lineNo + i, 1) = vDat(j, 1)
            resDat(lineNo + i, 2) = subSection
            resDat(lineNo + i, 3) = vDat(j, 2 + 2 * i)
            resDat(lineNo + i, 4) = vDat(j, 3 + 2 * i)

        Next

        i = 3
        subSection = "1400"

        If Len(vDat(j, 2 + 2 * i)) = 0 And Len(vDat(j, 3 + 2 * i)) = 0 Then
            lineNo = lineNo + 3
        Else
            resDat(lineNo + i, 1) = vDat(j, 1)
            resDat(lineNo + i, 2) = subSection
            resDat(lineNo + i, 3) = vDat(j, 2 + 2 * i)
            resDat(lineNo + i, 4) = vDat(j, 3 + 2 * i)
            lineNo = lineNo + 4
        End If

    Next

    ' Output the result to a new sheet
    Set shResult = Sheets.Add

    With shResult
        .Cells(1, 1).Value = "Part Code"
        .Cells(1, 2).Value = "Subsection"
        .Cells(1, 3).Value = "Time"
        .Cells(1, 4).Value = "Text"
    End With

    shResult.Range("A2").Resize(UBound(resDat, 1), 4) = resDat

End Sub
```